# how to display different pieces of text in UITextView using next & previous UIButton in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Let's say I have 3 pieces of text. I want to use a UITextView to display it. I have a Next and Previous button to help me cycle it through. What's the best way to solve this problem?. i am trying some code.. but it is not working for me..
Actally i need to display like this:
if i click next button i need to display like this.page of 1 of 3 and page 2 of 3 and page 3 of 3. if i click back button i need to display like this.page 3 of 3 page 2 of 3 and page 1 of 3.

```
-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton*)btn

{

int totalcount=3;

if(slokaText.hidden==NO)

{

if (btn.tag==1)

{

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[textStr count]);

if (counter<[textStr count]-1) {

counter++;

NSLog(@"%i", counter);

descriptionLbl1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}

else

{

if (counter>1)

{

counter--;

descriptionLbl1.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}        

}

else if (slokaMeaning.hidden==NO)

{

if (btn.tag==1)

{

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[textStr1 count]);

if (counter<[textStr1 count]-1) {

counter++;

NSLog(@"%i", counter);

descriptionLbl2.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr1 objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}

else

{

if (counter>1)

{

counter--;

descriptionLbl2.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr1 objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}

}

else if (meaning.hidden==NO)

{

if (btn.tag==1) 

{

NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[textStr2 count]);

if (counter<[textStr2 count]-1)

{

counter++;

NSLog(@"%i", counter);

descriptionLbl3.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr2 objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}

else

{

if (counter>1)

{            

counter--;

descriptionLbl3.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [textStr2 objectAtIndex:counter]];

NSLog(@"counter is :%d",counter);

countLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"page %d of %d",counter,totalcount];

}

}


}

}
```

Comment: what the error u faced surya

Comment: if i click next button displaying like this : page 1 of 3 and page 2 of 3.. if i click back button displaying like this: page 2 of 3 page 1 of 3 page 0 of 3.. like this....

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this..

assuming `currentPageNum`, `totalPageNum`,`yourTextView` are declared as global variable

```
- (IBAction)yourButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (sender.tag == 1) // assumed as back action
    {
        if (currentPageNum > 0)
        {
            currentPageNum -- ;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPageNum = totalPageNum; // add this line if you want to cycle
        }
    }
    else // assumed as next action
    {
        if (currentPageNum < totalPageNum)
        {
            currentPageNum ++;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPageNum = 1; // add this line if you want to cycle

        }
    }

    yourTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %li of %li",(long)currentPageNum,(long)totalPageNum];
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but i have some doubts.. plz come to stack over flow. i need to discuss with u

Comment: what are your doubts ?